Two right triangles inside a bigger triangle
In the given figure, ABC is a triangle.

We know that:
AF $\perp$ DC 
DE $\perp$ BC
AD = 2 * DB 
DC = 8 cm 
BC = 12 cm 
What is $\dfrac{\text{AF}}{\text{DE}}$?
I started by labeling the sides:

Then trying to use Pythagorean Theorem to relate the unknowns. I ended up with many equations but nothing to allow me to determine a value for AF/DE.

Also tried using Heron’s Formula to equate the area of the big triangle as a sum of $\triangle $ACD and $\triangle $BCD but was unable to solve.
$\triangle $ACD and $\triangle $ABC cannot be similar (setting up ratios yield two different values for AC in terms of $x$).
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

HINT:
Drop a perpendicular from $C$ to $AB$ (Let's call it $x$). Then,
$$[\triangle ACD]\implies AF\cdot DC=x\cdot AD$$
$$[\triangle BCD]\implies DE\cdot BC=x\cdot BD$$
Can you take it from here?
